# Uploading returns 502 Bad Gateway -> error_log: Cannot open shared object file: No such file or Directory

Tags: php, apache

I have the superlist theme. Every time I or another user wants to create a listing, Error **502 Bad Gateway** comes up. However, only if a lot of text or a large image is uploaded.

I looked at the `error_log`. It says:

> /home/www/wordpress/mywebsite/ads.txt Failed loading
>   /usr/local/ZendGuardLoader-php-7.2-linux-glibc23-x86_64/opcache.so:
>   /usr/local/ZendGuardLoader-php-7.2-linux-glibc23-x86_64/opcache.so:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I have already called my hoster. He says it's not the server.
Does anyone know how I can fix this?

This is everything I can change in the `php.ini`:

```
opchache.enable =1 opcache.memory_consumption=128
opcache.interned_strings_buffer=8 opcache.max_accelerated_files=4000
opcache.revalidate_freq=60 opcache.fast_shutdown=1
opcache.enable_cli=1
```

Settings I can't change are:

```
ysqli.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pdo_mysql.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
pdo_mysqli.default_socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysql.allow_persistent = Off mysqli.allow_persistent = Off curl.cainfo
= /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt upload_max_filesize = 50M
post_max_size = 50M display_errors = Off memory_limit = 256M
session.save_path = /tmp error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
date.timezone = 'Europe/Berlin' expose_php = Off [Zend]
zend_extension=/usr/local/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_[php].so
```

Answer (score -1):

Problem solved! It was the Nginx configuration! My hoster did it!